# wso2 am 2.0 ApiKeyValidator Authentication Errors

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

We've recently upgraded our fully functional WSO2 AM 1.10 to 2.0. The installation process gave no errors and seems to be complete. We can use the Publisher just fine. However, when we go to the Store, and go to a tab that lists all of the user's Applications, it fails, and the page is empty. The log shows:

```
 WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'MyUser[-1234]' at [2017-01-10 09:47:09,380-0500]

    WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2017-01-10 09:47:09,0380] from IP address IP-ADDRESS while trying to authenticate access to service APIKeyMgtSubscriberService

    ERROR - AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Can not retrieve OAuth application for the given consumer key : BigLongStringOfStuff org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided. 

at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531) 

at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)

at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)

at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)

at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)

at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.retrieveOAuthApplication(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:1683)

at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.getOAuthApplication(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:89)

at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.retrieveApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:234)

at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getClientOfApplication(ApiMgtDAO.java:2389)

at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getOAuthApplications(ApiMgtDAO.java:2353)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getApplications(ApiMgtDAO.java:4649)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.getApplications(APIConsumerImpl.java:3136)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.getApplications(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplications(APIStoreHostObject.java:3225)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

We are using a Read Only LDAP store, the configuration is here:

```
    <UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
            <AddAdmin>False</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>AdminGroup</AdminRole>
                <AdminUser>
                     <UserName>MyUser</UserName>
                     <Password>MyPW</Password>
                </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>

        <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager"> 
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property> 
            <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property> 
            <Property name="Disabled">false</Property> 
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property> 
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://MyServer:389</Property> 
            <Property name="ConnectionName">CN=MyUser,OU=1,OU=2,DC=a,DC=b,DC=c</Property> 
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">MyPW</Property> 
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">DC=a,DC=b,DC=c</Property> 
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=user)(|(memberOf=CN=MyGroup-Subscriber,OU=1,OU=2,DC=a,DC=b,DC=c)(sAMAccountName=MyUser))</Property> 
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(|(&amp;(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=?)(memberOf=CN=MyGroup-Subscriber,OU=1,OU=2,DC=a,DC=b,DC=c))(sAMAccountName=MyUser))</Property> 
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property> 
            <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute">displayName</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property> 
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">OU=Groups,OU=1,OU=2,DC=a,DC=b,DC=c</Property> 
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=MyGroup*))</Property> 
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=MyGroup?))</Property> 
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property> 
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property> 
            <Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property>
            <Property name="MultipleAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property> 
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property> 
            <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property> 
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property> 
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property> 
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property> 
        </UserStoreManager>

        <AuthorizationManager
            class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
        <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

In the Api-Manager.xml configuration for the ApiKeyValidator Key We have:

```
<APIKeyValidator>
<!-- Server URL of the API key manager -->
<ServerURL>https://MyURL:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>

<!-- Admin username for API key manager. 
<Username>MyUser</Username>
<!-- Admin password for API key manager. -->
<Password>MyPW</Password>

<KeyValidatorClientType>ThriftClient</KeyValidatorClientType>
<ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>10000</ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>
<EnableThriftServer>true</EnableThriftServer>
<ThriftServerHost>localhost</ThriftServerHost>

<KeyValidationHandlerClassName>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler</KeyValidationHandlerClassName>
```

This error did not occur in 1.10 with the same config file entries. Is there any idea as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out why this occurred - This will happen if the incorrect provider is listed in the user-mgt.xml file. If you see my file above, I am trying to use ReadOnly LDAP, but I have the RDBMS provider listed instead.

Changed this line and boom, everythign is functional again.